# SQL Server direct connection vs MS Access Database

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, oledbconnection

I am building an application in Visual Studio (winform) for a number of users, around 150, from all over the country and most connect to a VPN. This form will only be reading data.

The current application they are using has local tables in an Access database, and on open the application places a current copy of the database on the users machine to read from.

Now that I am building a new version of the application, I have SQL Tables created in 2014 SQL Management Studio to optimize performance and have a better recovery system for the data.

However, after much research, I can not determine which is best for my specific connection. Should I connect directly to my SQL tables or keep the process of placing a copy of the Access DB and connecting that way?

http://blog.nkadesign.com/2009/access-vs-sql-server-some-stats-part-1/

that article thinks access is faster

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fadb2742-d75a-49fb-a839-b2d4a9183998/oledbconnection-vs-sqlconnection?forum=vbgeneral

this article thinks SQL is faster

I would assume that direct connection to SQL is faster but with the process of placing a copy of the DB on their machine I'm not sure.

Any advise is appreciated. I have 8 links saved that provided minimal information and differing opinions.

Comment: What you are describing is one of the strangest ways to deal with data I have ever heard of. Are you seriously copying an entire access database to the client so that your data is read from there? Just read the data from your centralized sql server and be done with it. Throwing Access in the middle of this is completely insane.

Comment: Too many unknown factors here. But a local Access database file is very fast.

Comment: With regards to placing a copy of the data on each machine consider that concurrency is real issue with this type of approach. There is no ability to know if somebody else has changed something since you got the local copy of data. There are just so many reasons not to include Access here. You are doing what is known as "premature optimization" which is the process of choosing non-standard design approaches to deal with a performance problem that does not exist.

Comment: I didn't come up with the idea of placing the copy of the database on local machines, I am inheriting this application and looking to build a better version. From my understanding, this was done to increase performance of the application and logically it makes sense if there is a copy on there local machine it would work faster than connecting to our generally slow VPN. Since I am new to the whole process, and I know SQL is generally faster, it left me questioning which would be best on our network.

Comment: Do the users change or add data? If so then this approach of a local copy is going to be hugely problematic. I understand inheriting projects that are not well done. Maybe this is the time to move everything to a single database. :)

Comment: @SeanLange OP says "This form will only be reading data" but not clear if it is just this form or if the whole app has read-only access.

Comment: the whole app is read only, its basically a "report card" for a call center, so all it does it query data to display results. if a local copy was put on the machine it would have a password so no changes could be made.

Answer (score 0):

Here some stats
Access Max 2GB DB size  max 250 connections.

I will recommend you to move to SQL 2016 and explore memory tables if is only "READs"

Which version of SQL you have Express, Standard, Enterprise, Datacenter

Because your DB is Access less than 2GB ...
then SQL express edition is 10GB max BD size but SQL Query execute is on ONE CORE

the rest of the versions of SQL will perform as usual better than Access

where one beautiful website https://www.connectionstrings.com/

if you bringing data from Access to SQL you can use SSIS or write your own application

please collaborate more "but with the process of placing a copy of the DB on their machine I'm not sure."

you are planing to everyone to install SQL Express and replicate I do not understand that what do you mean??

You should have SQL server in one place

Comment: "but with the process of placing a copy of the DB on their machine I'm not sure." this is in regards to placing a copy of the MS Access DB on their machine, the houses the SQL tables. The VPN connection is generally quite slow that is why I wasn't sure

Comment: if you are using collocation you can play with DNS("make it local") or firewall of the SQL server and make the SQL visible only if people are login  in corporate side   no need VPN to SQL server...

Answer (score 0):

Well, given that you dumping the use of access as a database, you are adopting SQL server, then why introduce and use Access here at all?

You not made any case here to continue to use Access as a database. If you were using Access forms, reports etc., and then that is a VERY different issue. Since your development platform is Visual Studio and SQL server, then I cannot for any sensible reason figure out why you considering continued use of Access into this mix?

In the past you stated that the data was local. If the data can remain local to each user and is not required to be shared over some internet / VPN connection? Well then of course having a local data store as compared to one over the internet going to run a gazillion times faster, be far more reliable. And if the data sharing is not required among users, then I see no reason to adopt SQL server.

However if the data is to be shared then you need a central database. I mean of course a non-shared local data system that does not require the internet and always deals with local data is going to be far better in terms of performance since data remains on each workstation and other users don’t even care if they have internet connection at all.

So a comparison of local data in Access on each machine will be a zillion times faster in terms of speed than that of connecting to SQL server OVER some internet connection which is 1000’s of times slower than a local disk drive. So a 3 second delay will now become 3000 seconds (50 minutes). Such differences in performace are TYPICAL and COMMON. So 3 seconds will become 50 minutes. (again: common kinds of increase query times).

You cannot connect from Visual Studio to linked tables in Access which in turn link to SQL server (but even if you could – why not connect direct to SQL server and by-pass Access 100%).

The only case for continued use of Access would be if all users’ data is separate and no sharing of that data is required. However if that is the case, then why introduce SQL server at all? A simple “copy” of the access database will suffice for backup and I don't see any advantages of adopting SQL server as a central data store when no central data store is required.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is in one sense creating a database snapshot to be used for reporting.  That is an accepted practice and often used when the data does not need to be real time.

I can also understand keeping a local copy when dealing with VPN connectivity.  Each query the user submits need to pull data through the network, so unless the returned datasets are very small this solution seems appropriate.

Its a balance of how much data is returned per query against the total size of the data set.  You might not want to pull GB's of data when refreshing the local copy if you are only pulling KB's of data per query.

As for the local database technology, I think that you could use Access, especially if you want to use Access forms / reports / applications.  I also think you could have another type of local SQL db instead.  I dont think you need to worry about performance when choosing the local technology. As long as the data is local and does not travel via VPN across a network the difference in performance between Access and another modern database engine should be negligible.